# C# Unit testing resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I migrated from Java to C# and so I am wondering how to unit tests in C#. I remember using JUnit to test my Java applications. How can I unit test in C#? What are some good resources for unit testing in C# USING THE DEFAULT UNIT TESTING LIBRARY? I don't really need a port. A good resource would be like a nice PDF file, article, or better yet, a video!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) is effectively an idiomatic port of JUnit to the .NET land. There is also a unit testing framework built into Visual Studio, but since you're familiar with JUnit and NUnit is free, that would be my recommendation.

For mocking and stubbing, I like [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx).

Finally, Roy Osherove, has a nice book [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) which is a nice discussion of unit testing in general, but will also point you to other tools and resources.

Comment: +1 for Roy's book. It's not a very big book (as in many pages), but it's very well written. This book, combined with some experience on existing projects, got me up to speed on testing.

Comment: NUnit and JUnit are both ports of SUnit for Smalltalk.  +1 for Rhino Mocks.

Comment: Yep, Roy's book is outstanding.

Comment: So is Roy's blog - http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/. The new TypeMock Test Lint should be particularly useful if one is a newbie to unit testing. I particularly recommend one of Roy's screencasts where he critiques others' unit testing code - you learn a lot very quickly that way: http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/tags/TestReview/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You didn't mention what version of VS are you using but if it is VS 2010 RC give [Pex and Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) Visual Studio 2010 Powertools a try...

"**Pex automatically generates test suites with high code coverage**. Right from the Visual Studio code editor, Pex finds interesting input-output values of your methods, which you can save as a small test suite with high code coverage. Microsoft Pex is a Visual Studio add-in for testing .NET Framework applications."

"**Moles allows to replace any .NET method with a delegate**.  Moles supports unit testing by providing isolation by way of detours and stubs. The Moles framework is provided with Pex, or can be installed by itself as a Microsoft Visual Studio add-in."

Videos:

- ['Getting Started with Pex' video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Peli/Getting-started-with-Pex-in-Visual-Studio-2008)
- ['Getting Start with Moles' video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Peli/Moles-Replace-any-NET-method-with-a-delegate/)

Answer (score 2):

I like using MSTest since it's bundled with Visual Studio (most versions).

Also check out NUnit and xUnit.

For test runner I like using ReSharper.

Answer (score 2):

For mock objects another interesting library is [Moq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moq). It has some nice features, especially if you will test lambda expression and all the LINQ stuff (it has some support for that).

As for unit testing I use NUnit but strongly recommend reading *[Introduction to Test Driven Design (TDD)](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html)*.

Comment: +1 for Moq. I find it far more intuitive than Rhino Mocks. http://code.google.com/p/moq/

Answer (score 1):

What, no love for [MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try out [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org). You can also look at the unit test projects in Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2010.